# How to Catch Ctrl + C or trap signals on Alpine Docker when CMD is a shell script

Tags: linux, shell, docker, sh, alpine-linux

I have a dockerfile which is based on alpine linux 3.10 and has the following at the end as the instruction

`CMD ["sh", "/usr/local/bin/start"]`

content of `/usr/local/bin/start`

```
set -e
echo "Starting PHP-fpm and NGINX"
(php-fpm -D && nginx -g 'daemon off;')
```

Basically I want to run both process when the container starts, but it runs and starts both.
But when I press or send Ctrl+C or signals it does not stop the container.
I have tried many solutions for catching the signal but didnt work.

The above is just a small commands for demonstration

Comment: side-note: The idea of containerization is to have them separated.

Comment: I do know that, but there are certain use case for which a smaller application needs to be run like these to have more portability

Comment: I would use docker-compose. Anyhow, for what you want to do use [`supervisord`](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/multi-service_container/). (it's at the bottom of the linked page)

Comment: I want without supervisor as I need to have some one time commands and many other things

Comment: If you run them in two separate containers, and the `php-fpm`/`nginx` processes are the main processes in each container, then ^C in each will work as you expect.

Comment: @david i know about that but it does not give portability to the codes as it has to be shared by mounts, which is not what I wanted